# What kind of pipe should I install between my water meter and my house plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, water

What kind of pipe is used to hook house water pipes up to the city water meter?

I have a blue flexible hose between the meter and my 3/4 inch galvanized piping to the house.
The blue flex hose is prone to leaks, primarily at the connecting ends.

What kind of pipe should I replace it with, and what kind of adapters should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace the flex pipe  with a 3/4" PVC pipe using a threaded 3/4" connector. For a easier installation use a 3/4" union fitting at the meter. You could also install a shutoff valve at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Blue poly pipe, 25mm minimum. I'm not sure if you can connect to the meter; it may have to be the water company that does this. You must run at a depth of 2 1/2 feet while outside, and enter the building at that depth. You must lag the pipe when travelling through any masons walls, once inside you can travel where you wish. Do not kink the pipe as this will damage the seal.

The water company may want to inspect what you are doing. This was free for me. I also had to terminate an old supply they wanted to see that I had capped this properly. As for leaking connections, they may have worn out, be the wrong connection, or were just never done.

Comment: I believe the depth varies by location. E.g. in colder climates, you have to be below the frost line.

Answer (score -3):

Copper pipes run to the house.  PVC type piping is used for water that exits

Comment: Do you have a an explanation for why? Is it opinion, code in some location, or a technical difference?